# css styling for asp.net submenu items

Tags: asp.net, css, menuitem

using the asp:MenuItem control how does one style the submenuitem text?

Here is my markup;

```
 <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">

               <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" ToolTip="Home" Text="Home"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Products.aspx" Value="Products" Text="Products">
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="EnerBurn" Value="EnerBurn"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="EnerKool" Value="EnerKool"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="PEx(Particulate Extraction)" Value="PEx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="Investor Info" >
                         <asp:MenuItem Text="Press Releases" Value="Contact Support"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Quarterly Filings" Value="Send E-mail"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Annual Reports" Value="Contact By Phone"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Corporate Information" Value="Send E-mail"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Update Letters from Management" Value="Contact By Phone"></asp:MenuItem>
                   </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Contact" Value="Contact" NavigateUrl="~/Contact.aspx">
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Contact us" Value="Contact Support"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Login Request" Value="Send E-mail"></asp:MenuItem>
                      </asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>

            </asp:Menu>
        </div>
```

I want the submenuitems box to have rounded corners, I tried applying a .submenu class with the appropriate css which had zero effect.

Comment: Show your rendered html too!!!

Comment: from your comments i see the potential issue which i will work on, thank you

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? http://xkcd.com/979/